# How to access "this" keyword in <script setup> vue SFC

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am working on a simple scaffold for vite, vue and vuetify with typescript and I wanted to use the script setup version of SFC vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
```

One thing that I can't figure out is how to access "this" keyword properties?

for example in my old vue projects i could write this

```
this.$vuetify.themes.light.colors.primary
```

so i had the ability to access $vuetify anywhere in the component, but now in script setup mode "this" keyword is undefined;
How to access "this" properties?

Comment: Note: *Vue.js questions are highly version specific and should always be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3] in addition to this tag.*

Comment: It's Vue 3, i thought the SETUP word would make it clear that it is vue 3

Comment: OK, so you are using  [Vuetify 3 Alpha](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/), right ?

Comment: Yes i am using Vueify3 with the new modular createVuetify mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `setup` keyword in the `script` tag is a syntax sugar for:

```
const myComponent = createComponent({
  setup() {
    const foo = "may-the-force";
    let bar = "be-with-you";

    return {
      foo,
      bar
    }
  }
})
```

So naturally, in a `setup` function, you won't need `this` keyword because now you can just do:

```
bar = "be-not-with-you";

return {
  foo,
  bar
}
```

Now, when you initiated your Vuetify framework an instance is going to be kept somewhere. Something like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export const vuetify = createVuetify({ theme: {} });
```

Now that you have stored your `vuetify` instance somewhere you can import it just like you would do any other javascript/typescript file:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { vuetify } from "path/to/vuetify/instance";

console.log(vuetify.themes.light.colors.primary);

// You can even set dark mode if you prefer to
vuetify.framework.theme.dark = true;

</script>
```

---

### Edit

I'm guessing that things are a little bit different in Vue 3. After researching a little bit you can get the current Vue instance by using `getCurrentInstance`

```
<script setup>
    import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

    const app = getCurrentInstance()
    // it should be here in this instance the vuetify object with its properties
    console.log(app);
</script>
```

Comment: I have had imported vuetify in to my component the way you explained it, but it doesn't have the properties that the previous version $vuetify had, it only have one property called install which is a function that accepts a oneof type <App>

Comment: `export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: "#41b883",
          background: "#35495e",
          error: "#41b883",
          info: "#41b883",
          secondary: "#41b883",
          success: "#41b883",
          surface: "#41b883",
          warning: "#3d405b",
        },
        dark: false,
        variables: {},
      },
    },
  },
});`

Comment: Updated the answer. Please, see that I'm doing `export const vuetify = createVuetify()`. You import into your component the variable `vuetify` and not the `vuetify` framework itself.

Comment: Please take a look at screenshots to see it for yourself,
i have exported the createVuetify() as you said and yet i am getting only one property as a result of that function,

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/170V6pyNk4K9UXY-rT5yjjPiX9H8VvrsY?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks dear, i could reach $vuetify from getCurrentInstance.

Comment: `getCurrentInstance` is considered a private API, use with caution https://stackoverflow.com/q/72209080

Answer (score 0):

**Using provide and inject**

For e.g. I am using marcoschulte/vue3-progress package to show a loading bar at the top whenever routing happens.

According to vue3-progress docs, I can use this.$progress inside the script tag, but the this keyword is unavailable inside .

So in this scenario, I had to use provide and inject for props drilling.

In main.js or app.js (in laravel)

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './views/App.vue'
import store from './store/index'
import router from './router'
import Vue3Progress from 'vue3-progress'

const options = {
    position: "fixed",
    height: "3px",
    color: "#9d5e32",
}

let app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(Vue3Progress, options)
    // $progress is set automatically when I import vue3-progress at top
    .provide('progressBar', app.config.globalProperties.$progress) 
    .mount('#app')
```

In any SFC

```
<template>
    <vue3-progress />
    <TopNav />
        <router-view></router-view>
    <Footer />
</template>

<script setup>

    import Header from '../components/admin/Fixed/Header.vue'
    import Footer from '../components/admin/Fixed/Footer.vue'

    import { inject } from 'vue-demi'
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

    let router = useRouter()
    let progressBar = inject('progressBar')

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

        progressBar.start()
        next()
    })

    router.afterEach((to, from) => {

        progressBar.finish()
    })

</script>
```